# bash evaluate if statement from string

Tags: string, bash, if-statement, evaluate

I have a file which contains shell test statements.

I need to evaluate the expression.
For example:

```
a="something"
fromfile='[ "$a" == "something" ]'

if `$fromfile`; then
  echo "true"
else
  echo "false"
fi
```

It always throws false.
I tried with **``** and **eval**, but still not works.

What is the solution?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. Why do you want to store code in a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you just didn't hit the right syntax.  You really need `eval` for this:

```
a="something"
fromfile='[ "$a" = "something" ]'
if eval "$fromfile"
then
  echo "true"
else
  echo "false"
fi
```

But please read about the dangers `eval` imposes on the security side!  If you plan to execute strings you are *given*, if only in part, (by the user, from a data base, from a web site, ...) you might introduce a security risk.  (Consider `fromfile='rm -rf ~'` ← **In case you don't understand this: don't try this! It will remove everything from your home directory!**)

There are better options in most cases like declaring shell functions and passing their names instead of a complete syntax-containing string.

Comment: I think he was attempting to execute `eval` with the statement (e.g. `if $(eval "$fromfile"); then...` so that he was testing the return of `eval` instead of the result of the expression. Kudos for warning about the security implications. (e.g. file contents `'rm -r /'`, `read -r fromfile; eval "$fromfile"`)

Comment: This sript always prints true:)

But I found the answer: change the apostrophs
    fromfile="[ '$a' = 'something' ]"

Comment: @Tannis No, if you change the quotes like this, it will evaluate the variable `$a` just once, at assignment to `fromfile`.  I guess the intention was to be able to change `$a` later and get a different result.  But that's up to the OP ;-)

Comment: Try it out as it stands, it will print `true`.  Then issue `a="asdf"`, and then paste the `if … fi` again, it will print `false` then.

Comment: Ok, it is perfect now
Thank You!